# Trigger a Skype call via ADB

Tags: android, adb, skype

I want to trigger a Skype call (possibly to the  Echo/ Sound Test Service) via adb.
So far I was able to open skype via the following command

```
"adb shell am start -n com.skype.raider/com.skype4life.MainActivity"
```

but I could not progress further. Does anybody have any insights?

Comment: Get the APK and decompile it. Look into `AndroidManifest.xml` what other activities are exported.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I extracted the manifest and obtained the following 3 activities
  
inline `com.skype4life.MainActivity  
com.skype4life.BubbleActivity  
com.skype4life.SecondaryWindowActivity`  

I tried to cal the other 2 like so 
inline `
adb shell am start -n com.skype.raider/<activity>`

but I got  this type of error (example BubbleActivity)
 inline `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.skype.raider/com.skype4life.BubbleActivity } from null (pid=9640, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10330`

Comment: You can only call activities that have `exported=true` in AndroidManifest.xml. May be the MainActivity supports parameters. You can check that by decompiling it (e.g. using Jadx) and check if it receives parameters like shown here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#DisplayMessage

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d skype:echo123?call
```

I tried and it works.